# Viewing the forces involved in a contact interaction with `GetForceInWorld`

Tags: robotics, drake

I am attempting to record the forces acting on a given `RigidBody` throughout the simulation. I work with Drake using Python bindings and all the telemetry is recorded via a callback set in the `Simulator.set_monitor()`.

This callback is like that:

```
    def callback(self, root_context):
        nut = self._plant.GetBodyByName("nut")
        nut_context = self._plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)
        self.add_data(root_context.get_time(),
                      nut.EvalPoseInWorld(nut_context),
                      nut.EvalSpatialVelocityInWorld(nut_context),
                      nut.EvalSpatialAccelerationInWorld(nut_context),
                      nut.GetForceInWorld(nut_context, self._all_forces))
        return EventStatus.DidNothing()
```

The `_all_forces` object is initialized within the constructor in that way:

```
    self._all_forces = MultibodyForces(plant=self._plant)
```

I am able to log all the data as expected, non-zero accelerations and velocities of the monitored body during the contact phase of the simulation;

However, the `SpatialForce` is always zero in my case. That is contrary to my expectation that the force would been non-zero during the contact.
Additionally, when I apply a constant force to the body using `ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce()` this also does not register within the output of `GetForceInWorld`.

Am I misusing this API? Is there a known bug?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the force is zero is because GetForceInWorld() simply access the MultibodyForces container to retrieve whichever forces is stored for that body. If none, then it will return zero as in this case.

The only valid mechanism to retrieve contact forces is by accessing the ContactResult output port, i.e. MultibodyPlant::get_contact_results_output_port(). Once you get your ContactResults, you need to scan (separately) point contact and hydroelastic contact results and accumulate the ones that apply to your body (the nut) only. Let us know if you need help with that last part, we might have a snippet around that shows how to do this.

Small snippet to get the correct forces accumulated:

```py
    def callback(self, root_context):
        nut = self._plant.GetBodyByName("nut")
        nut_context = self._plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)

        contact_results = (
            self._plant.get_contact_results_output_port().Eval(nut_context))
        multibody_forces = MultibodyForces(plant=self._plant)

        # In this example we expect to only have point contact.
        assert 0 == contact_results.num_hydroelastic_contacts()

        # Process point contact results.
        for i in range(contact_results.num_point_pair_contacts()): 
        
          # Note consistent use of monogram notation, see Drake's module on this.
          contact_pair = contact_results.point_pair_contact_info(i)
          
          # We only accumulate forces on body "nut".
          if (contact_pair.bodyB_index() != nut.index() and
              contact_pair.bodyA_index() != nut.index()):
            continue
             
          # Make sure the sign is correct.
          sign = 1 if contact_pair.bodyB_index() == nut.index() else -1
          f_Bc_W = sign*contact_pair.contact_force()
          F_Bc_W = SpatialForce(tau=np.zeros(3), f=f_Bc_W)
          X_WB = plant.EvalBodyPoseInWorld(nut_context, nut)
          p_WBo = X_WB.translation()
          p_WC = contact_pair.contact_point()
          p_CBo_W = p_WBo - p_WC
          F_Bo_W = F_Bc_W.Shift(p_CBo_W)
          # Now we can perform a valid call to AddInForceInWorld().
          nut.AddInForceInWorld(nut_context, F_Bo_W, multibody_forces)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! I guess I've managed to put together the last part, using the drake unit-tests as examples. Please confirm, that my solution (posted here as a separate answer) is sound.

Comment: `p_CBo_W = p_WBo - p_WC` I think that the code is correct here. But, my impression was that this variable should've been rather called `p_BoC_W` to comply with monogram notation?

Comment: Hopefully we agree that `p_WBo - p_WC` is a (position) vector that goes from C to Bo? 
We note a posion vector from A to B with p_AB, see [example in the second row of the table here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__multibody__quantities.html). The last frame is the "expressed-in" frame, in this case the world frame W.

Comment: My bad, I agree now. The source of my confusion was that the monogram notation puts the "destination frame" in the left for transformations, i.e. `X_WB` (when a body frame is given in the world's frame). I see now, that it isn't like that for vectors.

Comment: humm... to me they look the same? but it depends how you read it. In my head, to remember the convention we use, I often read X_WB as "pose of B in W". For positions, then I read something like p_WB as "position of B with respect to W". Not quite the right technical phrasing, but it helps me to remember the convention.

Answer (score 0):

Using suggestions proveded by Alejandro here, I've changed my monitoring callback to this:

```
    def callback(self, root_context):
        nut = self._plant.GetBodyByName("nut")
        nut_context = self._plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context)

        contact_results = (
            self._plant.get_contact_results_output_port().Eval(nut_context))
        multibody_forces = MultibodyForces(plant=self._plant)

        assert 0 == contact_results.num_hydroelastic_contacts()
        for i in range(contact_results.num_point_pair_contacts()):
             current_f = contact_results.point_pair_contact_info(i) \
                     .contact_force()
             nut.AddInForceInWorld(nut_context, 
                                   SpatialForce(tau=np.zeros(3), f=current_f),
                                   multibody_forces)

        self.add_data(root_context.get_time(),
                      nut.EvalPoseInWorld(nut_context),
                      nut.EvalSpatialVelocityInWorld(nut_context),
                      nut.EvalSpatialAccelerationInWorld(nut_context),
                      nut.GetForceInWorld(nut_context, multibody_forces))
        return EventStatus.DidNothing()
```

This resulted in a log having the forces I expected to see there:
[image]

Comment: Nice improvement. Still you have a bug. From the documentation of `AddInForceInWorld()`, the spatial force `F_Bo_W` provided must be applied at the body B's origin Bo and expressed in the world frame W. However, from the documentation of `PointPairContactInfo`, `contact_force()` returns the force `f_Bc_W` applied on body B (you must check that bodyB_index() actually matches nut.index() or otherwise revert the sign) at contact point C, not body B's origin Bo. Therefore you must first shift (SpatialForce::Shift()) the spatial force at C to Bo for the call `AddInForceInWorld()` to be correct.

Comment: Example snippet added to the original answer. PTAL.